Micro-Ros Agent topic not present for non-root users
I'm working with a Raspberry Pi 4B running headless Debian (Raspbian) Bullseye Lite and an Arduino Nano RP2040 connected to the UART pins on the Pi. I have installed ROS2 Humble via these instructions here and managed to build the micro-ros agent after making two modifications/deviations from the setup instructions found here:

First, I removed/commented out <exec_depend>python3-vcstool</exec_depend> in package.xml. I couldn't install python3-vcstool with apt, so removing this line prevented that from happening during the build. I tried installing python3-vcstools instead, as that package was available to install
Second, instead of running ros2 run micro_ros_setup build_agent.sh, I ran colcon build --packages-up-to=micro_ros_agent --cmake-args -DUAGENT_USE_SYSTEM_LOGGER=ON

Along with all this, I had to make a slight modification to the micro-ros arduino library source code after downloading it (I basically changed mentions of Serial to Serial1 so that the Arduino could communicate with the Pi)
With the agent built and the modifications to the library made, I flashed the basic micro_ros_publisher example to the Arduino. Then I run ros2 run micro_ros_agent micro_ros_agent serial --dev /dev/ttyS0 -v6
At first glance everything connects. I get the expected messages from the micro-ros agent and the Arduino appears to be communicating as intended. However, the micro-ros agent topic does not show up when I open another terminal and run ros2 topic list
However, if I start the micro-ros agent as root, then open another terminal and run ros2 topic list as root, I do in fact see the micro-ros agent among the topics, and everything appears to be working as expected.
I tried seeing if I could bypass this issue by running the micro-ros agent with docker. However, the same issue still occurred--both on the host and in other containers.
Any reason why this is occurring? I feel it could be a build issue or how Ros2 Humble was installed, but if it occurs in Docker too I'm honestly not sure

After some further research, the issue was actually the ROS_DOMAIN_ID variable itself 
Once I unset that, everything worked as intended
The reason the root user was able to see the topic was because ROS_DOMAIN_ID was not set for the root user.
Had I known the answer was this simple, I probably wouldn't have asked this question. But at least I know now!
